# Ubuntu 16.04 Facebook has weird font in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, facebook

Im using 16.04 Ubuntu and installed Chrome. On some sites fonts are kind of shorter then normal and facebook has a completely weird very small font, but Firefox seems to be fine.

This is Chrome

[image]

This is Firefox

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the pull down menu and settings.
At the bottom, select advanced settings
scroll down to the heading "Web content"
there you can select font, size and zoom